# Chrome 26: ContentScript doesnt receive response callback from evenPage after an extension upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

We started getting this issue only after updating to Chrome 26.0.1410.43.

On normal circumstances everything seems to work fine.

- Content script sending message to event page using chrome.extension.sendMessage(message, callback)
- Event page receive the message and send back the response
- Content script receives the response from the event page.

But after the event page has been updated to a new version with the contentscript still on the same session, content script doesnt receive the responses from the event page anymore:

- Content script sending message to event page using chrome.extension.sendMessage(message, callback)
- Event page receive the message and send back the response
- Content script dont receive the response from the event page.
- Event page logs these in the console:

  - "tabs did not answer: 1"
  - Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

To reproduce in a local setup, update the version of the extension in the manifest, reload the event page from the Extensions page (chrome://extensions/) but dont refresh the tab where the content script is injected.

Comment: See http://crbug.com/168263.

Comment: thanks, seems the fix for that bug might be the one that is causing our issue.